# Probability of arrangement of letters following specific rules

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I have letters ABCDEFG (7 letters). I want to find the probability that if I shuffle the letters and arrange them randomly that B is first and A is last (but I can pick any arbitrary two letters).

I tried to simplify this:

If I have just two letters: A and B, there are $2! = 2$ ways to arrange them. And the probability of B being first and A being last is just $1/2$.

If I have three letters: A, B, C, there are $3! = 6$ ways to arrange them. The probability of B being first and A being last is $1/6$.

But this pattern breaks down somewhat for A, B, C, D. There are $4! = 24$ ways and the probability of B being first and A being last is $2/24$ because there are two ways for that to be true: BCDA, BDCA.

Is there a general rule for this problem?

Comment: The pattern has not broken down. In first case of two letters, between first and last letters there were $0$ letters and number of arrangements leaving first and last letters is $0! = 1$, in second case, you have $1$ letter in between the first and last so $1!$, in third case you have $4$ letters and there are $2$ letters in between the first and last so $2!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you know the first and last letters, all you need to count is the number of ways to arrange the letters in between. There are $(n-2)!$ ways to do it, where $n$ is the number of letters (including $A$ and $B$).

Since there are a total of $n!$ ways to arrange the $n$ letters (disregarding the restriction on $A$ and $B$), this gives us a probability of

$$\frac{(n-2)!}{n!} = \frac1{n(n-1)}.$$

Notice that this assumes (as in your given examples) that $A$ and $B$ figure in your $n$ letters (otherwise the probability is of course $0$), and also that the $n$ letters are all distinct.